# Exercise Help - Select the register number of the students with the average highest score

Tags: mysql, sql

I am studying SQL at my university, and I was practicing this exercise and got stuck! I have a database that stores all the exams passed by a student for a specific teach.

These are the tables in the database:

```
   Student(**number**, name, birthday)

   Exam(**student_number**, **teaching_code**, vote)  *(store the exams passed by the students with vote)*

   Teaching(**code**, name)
```

Where number is the primary key for the Student table, and code is for Teaching, "student_number" references "number" in Student, and "teaching_code" references "code" in Teaching.

The exercise asks to select the students’ numbers with the average highest score.

I know how to write a query which gives me a table containing the average for each students but I don't know how to select the highest from it or how to show the corresponding student number!

The solution with the limit command doesn't work if exists some students have the same highest average...

The query to show the average score per student is:

```
select  avg(e.vote) as Average from STUDENT s, EXAM e
where s.number = e.student_number
group by s.number
```

EDIT:
I tried the MAX function in SQL, I have tried this:

```
select  MAX( avg(e.vote) ) as Average from STUDENT s, EXAM e
where s.number = e.student_number
group by s.number
```

but it say "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function"

Probably the solution is with a nested query but I can't realize it.

Comment: since this is homework you should post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT MAX(Expression)
 FROM tables
 WHERE Condition`

You can check the [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php) on how to use `MAX` and find highest value.

If you want to select the `TOP` 5 or 10 or 20... highest, use the [TOP](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_code, MAX(avg_vote)
FROM (
    SELECT student_code, AVG( vote) as avg_vote
    FROM Exam
    GROUP BY student_Code ) t
GROUP BY student_code
```

I didn't checked that query.
May query to select that max average is be like that

Comment: Thank you but your query does exactly the same thing my query did to show the average score per student

Answer (score 0):

What a pity MySQL doesn't seem to support CTE's, then this would have been so simple.

```
select t.student_code, t.avg_vote
FROM (SELECT student_code, AVG(vote) as avg_vote
      FROM Exam
      GROUP BY student_Code) t
WHERE t.avg_vote = (select max(avg_vote) 
                    FROM (SELECT student_code, AVG(vote) as avg_vote
                          FROM Exam
                          GROUP BY student_Code))
```

Continue studying hard, being presented with a likely answer is far less useful than actually reaching the conclusion yourself. Actually, if you're lucky, my proposal will not work (I haven't tested) so that you will have to come up with the right modification yourself!

Comment: YOU DID IT! :D  
thank you very much!
I also understand how the query works, it it much simpler then how I expected. 
I got stuck because I tried to select the max from the average for each student  
Your query retrive the average for each student and compare it with the max average, it is the right way!